# TLS version: HttpClient only working when the security policy is set to tls 1.1

Tags: https, windows-10, httpclient, tls1.2, .net-4.7.2

I've got a windows forms app which is deployed through click once. The app was build with .net 4.7.2 and it uses the HttpClient API to access a couple of rest web services, which are hosted on an internal server. As you  might expect, the services can only be accessed through HTTPS and the server is configured to suppport all  TLS versions (btw, this is a 2016 windows server).

The intranet client app (ie, the windows forms app) is deployed across several internal sub-networks and everything is working well with the exception of a single PC (which belongs to a specific subnetwork - it's the only PC that is using this particular app). This PC will only be able to consume the services when the HttpClient is configured to use [TLS 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol).

Since we're using internal certificates (we have an internal certificate authority for our AD), I've already checked and the certificate with the public key of the entity is already present on the trusted certificate authorities container of the computer where the secure session can't be established through TLS 1.2.

The PC is running Windows 10 Pro (latest version), so it should support TLS 1.2. I've tried emulating the requests from Fiddler and the truth is that I'll only get the results when I [configure it](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/fiddler-and-modern-tls-versions) to use TLS 1.1.

Without setting the protocol to TLS 1.1, I can see that Fiddler says that the handshake hasn't been established and the service is never "executed".

Now, according to what I've read, I shouldn't have been getting any problems with the code. In fact, I shouldn't have to specify the TLS version (it looks like Windows 10 Pro has out of the box support for TLS 1.2 and that should be the default for WIndows 10. Since I'm using .NET 4.7.2, it should automatically use the system's default protocol), but the truth is that only using tls 1.1 (not tls 1.2!) allows for the secure channel to be established.

I've tried running the code in other machines and everything works out as expected (I can establish the secure channel with tls 1.1 or tls 1.2 or even let it use the system's default protocol).

Since I'm not really a network guy, can anyone point me in the right direction?  Do you guys think this can be caused by a firewall? Any ideas?

I mean, it looks like the PC recognizes the certificate used in HTTPS session (if that wasn't the case, then I wouldn't be able to use TLS 1.1, right?), but it seems like there's something in the way that won't let me use TLS 1.2...

Thanks.
Luis

Answer (score 0):

Check our official guidance for TLS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

If it is one machine problem, I would recommend to create a simple HelloWorld app doing simple request, targeting the same .NET Framework (4.7.2) and then test that on the specific machine vs. other machines. That will tell you for sure if the problem is in your app or in machine/network settings.

Comment: Hello. It only happens on machines that are on that specific network. I simply don't know what's the best way to see what's going on (I'm thinking that it might be related with the firewall, but not sure on how to prove it)...